# How transferable is JavaFX 1.3 knowledge to JavaFX 2.0?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-1

I'm embarking on a project to develop a desktop application but my expertise have been in the web application development realm.  I was about to refresh my knowledge on Swing programming when I learned on JavaFX which seems to be a much better alternative.  At least version 2.0 seems to fit that bill. My dilemma is that there are no books out on the topic.  I was wondering if reading up on 1.3 first would be of help?  Or is the syntax too, architecture, etc too different?  I understand that there was something  called JavaFX Script which is now gone in lieu of a Java API which is a bit why I'm wondering if reading up on 1.3 might be a futile effort?

Does anyone have any recommendations on learning resources other that JavaFX api, sample applications and such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously the syntax has changed, but if you already know Java, coding with JavaFX 2.0 will look familiar.

The one take away from existing books, is that most of the framework, controls, shapes, and effects, etc., from JavaFX 1.3 was ported over to JavaFX 2.0.  So the basic knowledge of the framework can be gleaned from one of the older books. That would help you in at least knowing what component to use and then allow you to research it further to see how it now works in JavaFX 2.0.

There is also a lot of helpful documents at [javafx.com](http://javafx.com). New books will be out within the next six months or so and may be available on-line sooner than that.

Comment: That's what I thought.  I'll read through the 1.3 book I have and then some of the 2.0 docs on the site.  Hopefully there'll be good 2.0 books (saw 1-2 coming up) but I can't wait until then :) Thanks.